# Best way to save PNG images for fast loading

Tags: php, performance, png, gd

I have some PHP code that processes a number of .PNG images, combining them pixel-by-pixel (so lots of `ìmagecolorat` calls). Some of these images can change, but a few are precalculated and rarely change.

The precalculated images are generated by GD and output in PHP using `imagepng`.

As they are read far more often than they are written, I'd like to optimize them for reading speed.

But what type of quality settings for `imagepng` is best to optimize reading performance in `imagecreatefrompng`?

Higher compression and filters create smaller files, but perhaps a bigger file with no compression or filters is faster to read?

Perhaps it's better to skip PNG files altogether and use raw, uncompressed binary files or something that can be read into a PHP array?

Comment: I think the difference is very small...I suggest you to create scripts ad hoc and measure the time. Otherwise you need to find other solutions like to use another language more fast than the PHP

Comment: I think you know that you can copy entire images or parts of it by using `imagecopy*()` functions. Using image magick should also yield better performance because all the pixel stuff is coded in C. But it depends on what you are actually doing with the pixels.

Comment: there may be a small amount of extra cpu time involved with extra compression levels, but you have to balance it against the overhead on the rest of the system. e.g. maybe you save 5% of disk bandwidth, but suck up 50% more cpu.  there is no way to answer this properly: benchmark various methods and see what fits best for you.

Comment: The GD lib always has the image data uncompressed in memory. Compressing and uncompressing image data should be a very small part of CPU time, but you can always save images in a GD native format.

Comment: @Sven I just tried using GD2 native format; uncompressed is actually slower than PNG, but compressed if about 3 to 4 times faster than PNG. Sadly, after some measurement, it turns out the majority of performance is lost in the processing itself.

Comment: As predicted. You can only optimize the "pixel pushing" itself, but haven't released any details.

Answer (score 0):

If you process *almost* the same files over and over again, you might want to stop messing with imagepng itself and move the logic one level higher. For example you may cache the finished images or function calls ( see for example [Caching function results in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540403/caching-function-results-in-php) ).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I had already implemented a disk-cache for results. A result cache doesn't impact the processing time itself however, it merely saves time on repeat calls.